# Why can the third case of master theorem not be applied here T(n)=2T(n/2)+nlgn

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity, master-theorem

Why is nlgn polynomially larger than n when:
*"Polynomially larger" means that the ratio of the functions falls between two polynomials, asymptotically*

Here n^0.1 < log n < n^0.4 , so nlgn should be polynomially larger than n and hence we should be able to apply third case of Master Theorem in it?

Here is the graph plot of y=n^0.1,y=log n and y=n^0.4
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vjq0j1ri3f

Comment: You really need to fix the formatting; this is unreadable as-is.

Answer (score 1):

> Here n^0.1 < log n < n^0.4 , so nlgn should be polynomially larger than n ...

Where did you get this idea?

See [this Math SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663818/does-the-logarithm-function-grow-slower-than-any-polynomial). Therefore, `log n` is less than *any* positive power polynomial; hence case **2** of the Master Theorem applies here, not 3. Proceed and you obtain `T(n) = Θ(n (log n)^2)`.